# Error: Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope in karma-jasmine

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

My controller:

```
angular.module('dr.search.components',[])
    .controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $timeout, $interval, $rootScope) {
    // code
});
```

Testing Code (inside describe):

```
var HomeController, $controller;
var scope, $state, $timeout, $interval,$rootScope;

beforeEach(module('dr.search.components'));
beforeEach(module('ui.router'));

beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$scope_, _$state_, _$timeout_, _$interval_, _$rootScope_) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
    scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    $state = _$state_;
    $timeout = _$timeout_;
    $interval = _$interval_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;

    HomeController = $controller('HomeCtrl', {$scope: scope, $state: $state, $timeout: $timeout, $interval: $interval, $rootScope: $rootScope});

}));

// Verify our controller exists
it('Home Controller should be defined', function() {
    expect(HomeController).toBeDefined();
});
```

I am testing my controller, if it exists or not. It is showing me Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove $scope from your `beforeEach`.

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$state_, _$timeout_, _$interval_, _$rootScope_) {
    ...
}));
```

Comment: Done it. Now its showing me this error:
Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite!

Comment: scopeProvider and jqLite are resolved now. jqLite error was because of this line in my controller   
angular.element('body').addClass('home');   Thanks for your help.